# ISO12 HTML5 audioplayer automatically play next song in background

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio, iso

I created a web audio player, but when I opened it in iPhone Safari and turned it in the background, it doesn't play the next song automatically. I have no idea how to resolve this problem.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div id="player">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <div class="ctrl">
        <div class="tag">
            <strong>Title</strong>
            <span class="artist">Artist</span>
            <span class="album">Album</span>
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="rewind icon margin-right"></div>
                <div class="playback icon margin-right margin-left"></div>
                <div class="fastforward icon margin-left"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="volume right">
                <div class="mute icon left margin-right"></div>
                <div class="slider left">
                    <div class="pace"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="loaded"></div>
                <div class="pace"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="timer left">0:00</div>
            <div class="line left">/</div>
            <div class="total_timer left">0:00</div>
            <div class="right margin-top">
                <div class="repeat icon margin-right"></div>
                <div class="shuffle icon margin-right margin-left"></div>
                <div class="list icon margin-left"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul id="" class="playlist"></ul>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
(function ($) {
        // Settings
        var repeat = localStorage.repeat || 0,
            shuffle = localStorage.shuffle || 'false',
            continous = true,
            autoplay = true,
            listDisplay = true,
            isclick = true,
            playlist = [
                {% for data in allData %}
                    {
                        title: '{{ data[0] }}',
                        artist: '{{ data[1] }}',
                        album: '{{ data[4] }}',
                        cover: '/image/{{ data[3] }}.jpg',
                        mp3: '/music/{{ data[2] }}.mp3',
                        ogg: ''
                    },
                {% endfor %}
            ];

        // Load playlist
        for (var i = 1; i <= playlist.length; i++) {
            var item = playlist[i - 1];
            $('.playlist').append('<li>' + i + '. ' + item.title + '</li>');
        }

        var time = new Date(),
            currentTrack = shuffle === 'true' ? time.getTime() % playlist.length : 0,
            trigger = false,
            audio, timeout, isPlaying, playCounts;

        var play = function () {
            //audio.load();
            audio.play();
            $('.playback').addClass('playing');
            timeout = setInterval(updateProgress, 500);
            isPlaying = true;
            var totalTime = parseInt(audio.duration % 60) < 10 ? '0' + parseInt(audio.duration % 60) : parseInt(audio.duration % 60);
            $('.total_timer').html(parseInt(audio.duration / 60) + ':' + totalTime);
        }

        var pause = function () {
            audio.pause();
            $('.playback').removeClass('playing');
            clearInterval(updateProgress);
            isPlaying = false;
        }

        // Update progress
        var setProgress = function (value) {
            var currentSec = parseInt(value % 60) < 10 ? '0' + parseInt(value % 60) : parseInt(value % 60),
                ratio = value / audio.duration * 100;

            $('.timer').html(parseInt(value / 60) + ':' + currentSec);
            $('.progress .pace').css('width', ratio + '%');
            $('.progress .slider a').css('left', ratio + '%');
        }

        var updateProgress = function () {
            setProgress(audio.currentTime);
        }

        // Progress slider
        $('.progress .slider').slider({
            step: 0.1, slide: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass('enable');
                setProgress(audio.duration * ui.value / 100);
                clearInterval(timeout);
            }, stop: function (event, ui) {
                audio.currentTime = audio.duration * ui.value / 100;
                $(this).removeClass('enable');
                timeout = setInterval(updateProgress, 500);
            }
        });

        // Volume slider
        var setVolume = function (value) {
            audio.volume = localStorage.volume = value;
            $('.volume .pace').css('width', value * 100 + '%');
            $('.volume .slider a').css('left', value * 100 + '%');
        }

        var volume = localStorage.volume || 0.5;
        $('.volume .slider').slider({
            max: 1, min: 0, step: 0.01, value: volume, slide: function (event, ui) {
                setVolume(ui.value);
                $(this).addClass('enable');
                $('.mute').removeClass('enable');
            }, stop: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('enable');
            }
        }).children('.pace').css('width', volume * 100 + '%');

        $('.mute').click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('enable')) {
                setVolume($(this).data('volume'));
                $(this).removeClass('enable');
            } else {
                $(this).data('volume', audio.volume).addClass('enable');
                setVolume(0);
            }
        });

        // Switch track
        var switchTrack = function (i) {
            if (i < 0) {
                var track = currentTrack = playlist.length - 1;
            } else if (i >= playlist.length) {
                track = currentTrack = 0;
            } else {
                track = i;
                currentTrack = i
            }

            $('audio').remove();
            loadMusic(track);
            if (isPlaying == true) play();
        }

        // Shuffle
        var shufflePlay = function () {
            var time = new Date(),
                lastTrack = currentTrack;
            currentTrack = time.getTime() % playlist.length;
            if (lastTrack == currentTrack) ++currentTrack;
            switchTrack(currentTrack);
        }

        // Fire when track ended
        var ended = function () {
            pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            playCounts++;
            if (continous == true) isPlaying = true;
            if (repeat == 1) {
                play();
            } else {
                if (shuffle === 'true') {
                    shufflePlay();
                } else {
                    if (repeat == 2) {
                        switchTrack(++currentTrack);
                    } else {
                        if (currentTrack < playlist.length) switchTrack(++currentTrack);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var beforeLoad = function () {
            var endVal = this.seekable && this.seekable.length ? this.seekable.end(0) : 0;
            $('.progress .loaded').css('width', (100 / (this.duration || 1) * endVal) + '%');
        }

        // Fire when track loaded completely
        var afterLoad = function () {
            if (autoplay == true) play();
        }

        // Load track
        var loadMusic = function (i) {
            var item = playlist[i],
                newaudio = $('<audio autoplay preload="auto" id="audio">').html('<source src="' + item.mp3 + '"><source src="' + item.ogg + '">').appendTo('#player');
            nowcover = $('.background').css("background-image").replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace('\"', '').replace('\"', '');
            $('.cover').html('<img src="' + item.cover + '" alt="' + item.album + '">');
            $('.tag').html('<strong>' + item.title + '</strong><span class="artist">' + item.artist + '</span><span class="album">' + item.album + '</span>');
            $('.playlist li').removeClass('playing').eq(i).addClass('playing');
            if (nowcover == item.cover) {
            } else {
                if (isclick) {
                    isclick = false;
                    $('.background').fadeOut(0, function () {
                        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + item.cover + ')')
                    }).fadeIn(1500);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        isclick = true;
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
            audio = newaudio[0];
            audio.volume = $('.mute').hasClass('enable') ? 0 : volume;
            audio.addEventListener('progress', beforeLoad, false);
            audio.addEventListener('durationchange', beforeLoad, false);
            audio.addEventListener('canplay', afterLoad, false);
            audio.addEventListener('ended', ended, false);
        };

        loadMusic(currentTrack);
        $('.playback').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('playing')) {
                pause();
            } else {
                play();
            }
        });
        $('.rewind').on('click', function () {
            if (shuffle === 'true') {
                shufflePlay();
            } else {
                switchTrack(--currentTrack);
            }
        });
        $('.fastforward').on('click', function () {
            if (shuffle === 'true') {
                shufflePlay();
            } else {
                switchTrack(++currentTrack);
            }
        });
        $('.playlist li').each(function (i) {
            var _i = i;
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                switchTrack(_i);
            });
        });

        if (shuffle === 'true') $('.shuffle').addClass('enable');
        if (repeat == 1) {
            $('.repeat').addClass('once');
        } else if (repeat == 2) {
            $('.repeat').addClass('all');
        }

        $('.repeat').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('once')) {
                repeat = localStorage.repeat = 2;
                $(this).removeClass('once').addClass('all');
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('all')) {
                repeat = localStorage.repeat = 0;
                $(this).removeClass('all');
            } else {
                repeat = localStorage.repeat = 1;
                $(this).addClass('once');
            }
        });

        $('.shuffle').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('enable')) {
                shuffle = localStorage.shuffle = 'false';
                $(this).removeClass('enable');
            } else {
                shuffle = localStorage.shuffle = 'true';
                $(this).addClass('enable');
            }
        });

        $('.list').on('click', function () {
            if ($('.playlist').hasClass('display-none')) {
                $(this).addClass('enable');
                $('.playlist').removeClass('display-none');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('enable');
                $('.playlist').addClass('display-none');
            }
        });

        $(document).keydown(function (event) {
            var e = event;
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.btn').click()
                }, 0);
                e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
            }
        });

        $('.btn').click(function () {
            var filter_word = $('.search').val().trim();
            if (filter_word) {
                window.location.href = '/?filter_word=' + filter_word;
            }
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

automatically paly next song works in PC web browser， but not works in iPhone, what can I do?

Comment: Is this occurring when the phone is unlocked? Is it only happening on Safari or have you tested on other mobile devices and browsers?

Comment: @ScottieG Whether unlocked or locked,It will occur as long as it is in the background. I had test it in my friends iPhone X,  The  test result just same with my test,  and we all use Safari.

Comment: Have you tested it in any other mobile browsers?  It would be good to know if it's only affecting one browser or more. That way we can help with the relevant code

Comment: yeah, I have  tested it in Android browsers, It also doesn't work. It seems to only work on PC browsers.